# Generate an apk failed on React native

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, react-native, react-navigation

When i'm build my React native project using this command

```
gradlew bundleRelease
```

Give a big error on `Task :app:mergeReleaseResources`

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.

  > [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_stack_src_views_assets_backicon] C:\Users\victo\Documents\git\melhor\app-user\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_stack_src_views_assets_backicon.png  [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_stack_src_views_assets_backicon] C:\Users\victo\Documents\git\melhor\app-user\android\app\build\generated\res\react\release\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_stack_src_views_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  >   [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_stack_src_views_assets_backicon] C:\Users\victo\Documents\git\melhor\app-user\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_stack_src_views_assets_backicon.png  [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_stack_src_views_assets_backicon] C:\Users\victo\Documents\git\melhor\app-user\android\app\build\generated\res\react\release\drawable-mdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_stack_src_views_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  >   [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_stack_src_views_assets_backiconmask] C:\Users\victo\Documents\git\melhor\app-user\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_stack_src_views_assets_backiconmask.png  [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_stack_src_views_assets_backiconmask] C:\Users\victo\Documents\git\melhor\app-user\android\app\build\generated\res\react\release\drawable-mdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_stack_src_views_assets_backiconmask.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  >   [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_address_emptyaddress] C:\Users\victo\Documents\git\melhor\app-user\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\src_assets_address_emptyaddress.png    [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_address_emptyaddress] C:\Users\victo\Documents\git\melhor\app-user\android\app\build\generated\res\react\release\drawable-mdpi\src_assets_address_emptyaddress.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  >   [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_address_faildelivery] C:\Users\victo\Documents\git\melhor\app-user\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\src_assets_address_faildelivery.png    [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_address_faildelivery] C:\Users\victo\Documents\git\melhor\app-user\android\app\build\generated\res\react\release\drawable-mdpi\src_assets_address_faildelivery.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  >   [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_brands_bayer] C:\Users\victo\Documents\git\melhor\app-user\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\src_assets_brands_bayer.png    [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_brands_bayer]

This error is larger and have more "Duplicated resources".

I see that is a problem with the images i use inside the aplication But that is only one image with those names with the name inside the app, why is "duplicated"?

and other assets like "node_modules_reactnavigation_stack_src_views_assets_backicon" assets on react navigation that i dont have control.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This problem ocurrs because the project builded duplicates files.

To resolve it, you need delete the files inside of `res` folder.

Delete `drawable` folder and `raw` folder.

Your project directory will be like that:

[image]

Comment: Tanks, i had already solved doing this, but thanks!

Comment: +1 This is just a quick fix. The next questions are "why it's creating duplicate data every time" and "how to solve it"?